# Cannot compile project using BMI2 after updating to Xcode 12.2

Tags: xcode

My computer auto-updated Xcode to 12.2 recently, and suddenly I couldn't compile code that is using Intel intrinsics (BMI2 in the case of this project). I got the error:

> clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'

But, of course it does support this, as it was working yesterday. Any idea what is going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 12.2 changed the default compiler settings. In their release notes they state:

> Standard Architectures build setting defaults to Universal, and Xcode offers to upgrade your project if needed

Since Intel intrinsics are not supported on ARM, it will break your build if you are using them.

The solution is to go to your project build settings, show all settings, and then under architectures, add `arm64` as an excluded architecture. Once this is done, everything should compile again. (Supporting ARM is a separate question.)